# yarn can't find git in windows, but it's installed and available in the PATH - what to do?

Tags: git, yarnpkg

I have a dependency like so in my package.json:

```
        "mypackage": "git+git@git.company.user/repo.git",
```

but when I run `yarn` I get this every time:

```
$ yarn
yarn install v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find the binary git
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

I have git installed in my Windows machine at C:\Program Files\Git

And I have added it to the env variable PATH:

[image]

I also confirmed that it is available in the PATH within the git bash where I'm running yarn:

```
$ echo $PATH
...:/c/Program Files/Git/bin:/c/Program Files/Git/cmd
```

I'm using yarn 1.22.5 (the latest). Been trying to solve this for hours...

What else can I do? What am I missing?

Comment: mypackage is private repository ?

Comment: @Kasiriveni yes, but I do have access to it. I can access it with git without entering credentials (user + an access token already stored, etc). Is there something else I need to do to allow yarn to access it as well?

Comment: try yarn login in your terminal  ,enter your details  and  do yarn install